# Ruby library with least footprint to host a very simple single endpoint API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I have a very simple number crunching Ruby function that I want to make available via a web API. The API is essentially a single endpoint, e.g. `http://example.com/crunch/<number>` and it returns JSON output.

I can obviously install Rails and implement this quickly. I require no more help from a 'framework' other than to handle HTTP for me. No ORM, MVC and other frills.

On the far end, I can write some Ruby code to listen on a port and accept GET request and parse HTTP headers etc. etc. I don't want to re-invent that wheel either.

What can I use to expose a minimal API to the web using something with the least footprint/dependencies. I read about Sinatra, Ramaze, etc., but I believe there can be a way to do something even simpler. Can I just hack some code on top of Rack to do what I am trying to do?

Or in other words, what will be the simplest Ruby equivalent of the following code in nodejs:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  var ans = crunch(number);
  res.end(ans);
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: By "Rake" I suspect you mean "Rack". Rake is "Ruby Make", whereas Rack is the middle-layer under Rails, Sinatra, etc. You can answer your question by reading the documentation for Rack, Sinatra, Ramaze, and see what their minimal code is to create a server. Using something with the least footprint/dependencies could mean you write a lot more code, so which is more important, your time and ease of debugging, or footprint?

Comment: @theTinMan, I absolutely meant Rack. I'll edit the question. I'll check the Rack code. Thanks for the direction

Comment: I'd check Sinatra's really. It's amazing how little code it takes to make a usable server. `get '/' { 'hi' }` is the gist of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem like you want to use [Rack](http://rack.github.io) directly.  "[Rack from the Beginning](http://hawkins.io/2012/07/rack_from_the_beginning/)" is a decent tutorial that should get you started.

It'll probably look something like this:

```
class CrunchApp
  def self.crunch(crunchable)
    # top-secret crunching
  end
  def self.call(env)
    crunchy_stuff = input(env)
    [200, {}, crunch(crunchy_stuff)]
  end
  private
  def self.input(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    request.params['my_input']
  end
end

Rack::Server.start app: CrunchApp
```

But I must say, using that instead of something like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) seems silly unless this is just a fun project to play with things. See their 'Hello World':

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Comment: Thanks @nick, you posted the answer while I was still writing the pseudo code in nodejs and it looks exactly similar. I wish I could upvote the answer if I had enough points.

Comment: Agreed about Sinatra. It's plenty powerful and results in really clean code. Toss in Haml support and Sequel and it's my go-to.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby-Grape](http://www.ruby-grape.org) is a good option for your use case. It has a minimal implementation over Rack that allow the creation of simple REST-API endpoints.

[Cuba](http://cuba.is) is another good option with a thin layer over Rack itself.[sample post](http://serdardogruyol.com/using-cuba-to-build-lightweight-apis/)

If you are familiar with Rails you can use the [Rails API gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) which is very well documented with minor overhead. Remember also that Rails-API will be part of [Rails 5](http://wyeworks.com/blog/2015/6/11/how-to-build-a-rails-5-api-only-and-backbone-application).

Last, but not last you can implement it on Rack directly.